# .htaccess redirect /shop/ but not /shop/product

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from:

`/shop/` to `/shop/pay-your-bill/`

At the moment in my .htaccess file I have:

```
Redirect /shop/ http://url/shop/pay-your-bill/
```

This however results in this error:

The web page at URL/shop/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill/pay-your-bill has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Is there a way to redirect shop to pay-your-bill correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: removed html tag since nothing to do with html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/shop/?$ /shop/pay-your-bill/
```

Or if you can use mod_rewrite then use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^shop/?$ /shop/pay-your-bill/ [L,R,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
rewriterule ^/shop/(.*) http://url/shop/pay-your-bill/ [r=301,nc]
```